# Directory.GetFiles throws exception "could not find part of the path"

Tags: c#, html, image, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm building a simple image board with Blazor WASM. OnInitialize I want to get all file names in the "image" folder, located in wwwroots. Here is my code with two approaches. The second approach is commented out. Both are giving me the same error message.

```
public partial class Index
{
    string str = "";
    string[] allfiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"images", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        foreach (string file in allfiles)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }

    //DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"images");

    //FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt"); //Getting Text files

    //foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    //{
    //  Console.WriteLine(str = str + file.Name);
    //}


}
```

[image: Path]

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix that? I feel so dumb, because I'm like "But there is the image folder.. Why doesn't it work?"
It also doesn't work, if use @"/images" instead of @"images"

Comment: I've never used Blazor or WASM, but they run on the client. Client access to things like the file system is _**very**_ restricted

Comment: Your code is running on the client, not the server.  You either need to run Blazor Server to directly access the file system, or write an API to provide that information to the client.

Comment: You cannot do it from client. It would mean you can get all files from any website. You need server app for this (not blazor server, but something running in your server (typically Blazor wasm hosted )).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web Assembly runs in the same browser sandbox that JavaScript uses and so has many of the same limitations. The security context is the same, and Web Assembly cannot access the underlying hardware, operating system or file system outside of the sandbox.

Not sure if it will be useful for your application but you can get the static files inside wwwroot folder via http call to the server.

```
[Inject]
HttpClient Client { get; set; }

async Task GetPhoto()
{
    var photo = await Client.GetByteArrayAsync("images/bgtest.png");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed! But for future ppl seeking for help in the sam situation, I have to notice that I also splitted the string afterwards, because the output gives the full local path which is not allowed. So I splitted it to /pics/example.png/